# How to get Instagram photo posts when entering profile username using Instagram API

Tags: php, instagram, instagram-api

I have the website: https://instamama.net/ where is the on this step of packages: https://instamama.net/buy-instagram-likes/ user need add the username (now it is just simple post url aditing) and my idea is to display their Instagram Profile Posts photos - so in easy words I would like to make a script which gets Instagram users profile posts picture by just entering the username - something like this one works, please see the screenshot: http://prntscr.com/sm2kb0

Using this code I plan get the User ID

```
$access_token = 'YOUR ACCESS TOKEN';
$username = 'username';
$user_search = rudr_instagram_api_curl_connect("https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/search?q=" . $username . "&access_token=" . $access_token);
// $user_search is an array of objects of all found users
// we need only the object of the most relevant user - $user_search->data[0]
// $user_search->data[0]->id - User ID
// $user_search->data[0]->first_name - User First name
// $user_search->data[0]->last_name - User Last name
// $user_search->data[0]->profile_picture - User Profile Picture URL
// $user_search->data[0]->username - Username

$user_id = $user_search->data[0]->id; // or use string 'self' to get your own media
$return = rudr_instagram_api_curl_connect("https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/" . $user_id . "/media/recent?access_token=" . $access_token);

//var_dump( $return ); // if you want to display everything the function returns

foreach ($return->data as $post) {
    echo '<a href="' . $post->images->standard_resolution->url . '"><img src="' . $post->images->thumbnail->url . '" /></a>';
}
```

Then I`m trying to use this code:

```
$access_token = 'YOUR ACCESS TOKEN';
$username = 'rudrastyh';
$user_search = rudr_instagram_api_curl_connect("https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/search?q=" . $username . "&access_token=" . $access_token);
// $user_search is an array of objects of all found users
// we need only the object of the most relevant user - $user_search->data[0]
// $user_search->data[0]->id - User ID
// $user_search->data[0]->first_name - User First name
// $user_search->data[0]->last_name - User Last name
// $user_search->data[0]->profile_picture - User Profile Picture URL
// $user_search->data[0]->username - Username

$user_id = $user_search->data[0]->id; // or use string 'self' to get your own media
$return = rudr_instagram_api_curl_connect("https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/" . $user_id . "/media/recent?access_token=" . $access_token);

//var_dump( $return ); // if you want to display everything the function returns

foreach ($return->data as $post) {
    echo '<a href="' . $post->images->standard_resolution->url . '"><img src="' . $post->images->thumbnail->url . '" /></a>';
```

Could somebody tell me what I`m doing wrong? Many thanks